# Can use image of an iphone for an ios app

Tags: iphone, image, app-store

I want to show iphone orientation in my ios app in the settings view.  I want to show an iphone lanscape and portrait.  Is it legal to use an image of a iphone for that. Will it rejected by apple because of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer :** NO, it is not allowed.

Sooner or later some App Store reviewer will reject your binary on the grounds of copyright/trademark infringement.

Source : Personal experience. lol. (Of course, I'm not speaking on behalf of Apple, but...)